# How do I solve "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON" in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, json, reactjs

I'm using React. To query some data from my MySQL database, I created another NodeJS back-end server and did this code.

```
  var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    port: "3306",
    database: "my_books",
    user: "root",
    password: "pokemon2345"
  });
  con.connect();

  var sql = JSON.parse(req.query.msg);
  console.log(sql);
  var answer = con.query(sql);
  con.end();
  res.send(JSON.stringify(answer));
```

This is my code in the main React app.

```
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var jsql = JSON.stringify(sql);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      debugger;
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var response = this.responseText;
        toast.success(typeof response);
      }
    };
    request.open(
      "GET",
      "http://localhost:3001/retrieve_books" + "?msg=" + jsql,
      true
    );
    request.send(jsql);
```

I am unable to figure out why this error is happening and how my code is circular?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: the code isn't circular, the data is

Comment: note, in every nodejs mysql library I've ever used, `.query` is asynchronous and either returns a promise or takes a callback - your code looks like you expect a *synchronous* result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Circular JSON means, there is a reference to an object inside the object, which makes the JSON.stringify not possible.

in your case, res.send(JSON.stringify(answer)) could be the problem. The response of con.query(sql) may not be a simple object.

Also, the function is asynchronous and expects a callback to get the answer (I am assuming you are using mysqljs https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql)

give more details to explain further, but the underlying problem is the value of the variable "answer"

Comment: happy it helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Dhananjai's answer. I've stumbled upon this issue a few times over and over in the past. I made an [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/circular-structure-stringify) to get around this problem and safely stringify the object.